# store varying numbers of ARIMA regression coefficients to array/list, how to pad zeros to make array(list elements) length equal?

Tags: r, arrays, neural-network, rolling-computation

**I am doing a rolling window regression of MSFT stock, my advisor asks me to plot all the coefficients with different window size. Below is my code:**

```
library(quantmod);library(forecast);library(tseries);library(timeSeries);library(xts);
#log and diff 
getSymbols("MSFT", src="yahoo",from ="1986-03-13", to ="2021-10-08") 
cls_p <- na.omit(MSFT[,4]);lg_diff_p <- diff(log(cls_p), lag=1);lg_diff_p <- lg_diff_p[!is.na(lg_diff_p)];

# calculate how many times the regression will be done 
row_num <- nrow(lg_diff_p); 
window_size <- 1400; 
rolling_time <- (row_num - window_size) ;

#initiate a list to store coefficients
coef_list_AR <- NULL; coef_list_MA <- NULL; dynamic array
num_0_AR <- 0; num_0_MA <- 0;

#for loop to regress and get the coefficients
for (i in 1:rolling_time) {
  start_ <- i; end_ <- row_num-rolling_time+i; 
  print(c(i,end_));

  # regress with auto.arima()
  fit_ <- auto.arima(coredata(lg_diff_p[c(i: end_),]))
  paste(fit_, collapse = "\n"); print(fit_)

  # intercept the coefficients of AR part and MA part
  result <- substring(fit_, 7, 11)
  result <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(result, split = ",")))

  # initiate 2 arrays store AR and MA coefficients for each regression
  temp_AR <- c(); temp_MA <- c();

  # if AR part with no coefficient, assign 0 to coef_list_AR[[i]]
  if(result[1] != 0){
    for (j in seq(1, by = 1, length = result[1])) {
      temp_AR[j] = fit_$coef[j]
    }
    dim(temp_AR) <- c(1, result[1]) #zero vector can't be dimmed
  }else{
    temp_AR <- c(0); num_0_AR <- num_0_AR + 1
  }

  # if MA part with no coefficient, assign 0 to coef_list_MA[[i]]
  if(result[3] != 0){
    for (k in seq(1, by = 1, length = result[3])) {
      temp_MA[k] = fit_$coef[k]
    }
    dim(temp_MA) <- c(1, result[3]) #zero vector can't be dimmed
  }else{
    temp_MA <- c(0); num_0_MA <- num_0_MA + 1
  }

  #assign coefficient array to corresponding list
  coef_list_AR[[i]] <- temp_AR;coef_list_MA[[i]] <- temp_MA;
}

#save AR coefficient list to csv file
lapply(coef_list_AR, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'coef_list_AR_1400.csv' , append= T, sep=',' ,row.names = F, col.names = F))

#save MA coefficient list to csv file
lapply(coef_list_MA, function(x) write.table( data.frame(x), 'coef_list_MA_1400.csv' , append= T, sep=',' ,row.names = F, col.names = F))
```

**Data in the exported csv file is like this:**
**I don't know if package ggplot is applicable to plot with this kind of blank values, so at first I decide to plot with MS Excel.**

**So I try to pad each regression result array, code is shown in next part**

```
AR coefficient:
               only second and last line get 5 coefficients
               other lines only have lag-1 coefficient, and the left 4 are blank

 lag1               lag2            lag3             lag4           lag5
-0.475334139                
-0.819090716    -0.685436914    -0.529064191    -0.370352261    -0.185937604
-0.475503503                
-0.475499248                
-0.475492434                
-0.475488969                
-0.475582259                
-0.819691041    -0.686080515    -0.529346257    -0.370459152    -0.18582037
```

**What I expect is like below, so blank places would be padded with zeros, it can be done by MS Excel replacement function.**

**Is there way to pad within the codes with specified R function**

```
AR coefficient
 lag1               lag2            lag3             lag4           lag5
-0.475334139          0              0                0             0
-0.819090716    -0.685436914    -0.529064191    -0.370352261    -0.185937604
-0.475503503          0              0                0             0
-0.475499248          0              0                0             0
-0.475492434          0              0                0             0
-0.475488969          0              0                0             0
-0.475582259          0              0                0             0
```

**Then I add some code, to find the largest length in each element of the coef_list_AR list for addressing the list index**

```
for(m in seq(1, by=1, length = len_coef_list_AR)){
  temp_len_ <- length(coef_list_AR[[m]]);
  if(temp_len_ > max_AR_p ) { max_AR_p <- temp_len_ }
}
```

**And try to pad zeros for those regression results those with less lags(less coefficients).**

**To address [[m]][n], if length of [[m]] is not the largest, then pad the bland places with zero**

```
for(n in seq(1, by=1, length = len_coef_list_AR)){
  temp_len_ <- length(coef_list_AR[[n]])
  len_gap_ <- max_AR_p - temp_len_
  if(temp_len_ < max_AR_p){
    for(p in seq(1, by=1, length=len_gap_)){
      coef_list_AR[[n]][temp_len_ + p] <- 0;
    }
    dim(coef_list_AR[[n]]) <- c(1:max_AR_p)
  }
}
```

**But this leads to unexpected result, zeros are listed in the different lines of the csv file**

```
AR coefficient
 lag1               lag2            lag3             lag4           lag5
-0.475334139          
0                
0                 
0               
0
-0.819090716    -0.685436914    -0.529064191    -0.370352261    -0.185937604
-0.475503503          
0                
0                 
0               
0
-0.475499248          
0                
0                 
0               
0
-0.475492434          
0                
0                 
0               
0
-0.475488969          
0                
0                 
0               
0
-0.475582259          
0                
0                 
0               
0
```

**hope someone who can give me some suggestions, thanks a lot**

Comment: `lengths(coef_list_AR) <- max(lengths(coef_list_AR))` will pad with `NA`, which seems more sensible to me.

Comment: Hi Roland, I haven't tried, but I think this won't work, because lengths(coef_list_AR) is changing along the regression loop.

Comment: Obviously, you do this after the `for` loop, right before the loop that saves to files.

Comment: In the later half of the code, where to find the max length, it's still dynamic.

Comment: Got it, thanks for replying again.

Comment: Hi Roland, Rstudio reports error:

Comment: > lengths(coef_list_AR) <- max(lengths(coef_list_AR))
Error in lengths(coef_list_AR) <- max(lengths(coef_list_AR)) : 
  could not find function "lengths<-"

Comment: `mylist <- lapply(mylist, "length<-", max(lengths(mylist)))`

Comment: Thank you very much, Roland, would you mind copying your reply as the answer so that these replies can be presented as answers?